# How to run Tomcat server on koding.com (using Liferay bundle)

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, koding

I have installed Liferay Tomcat bundle on koding VM, When I run the `startup.sh` if give below logs on screen then but no message for server status.

```
vasimkp: ~ $ cd /home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin
vasimkp: ~/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin $ sudo ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/vasimkp/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

vasimkp: ~/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/bin $
```

I am trying to access it using http://liferay.vasimkp.koding.io:8080 but not able to get it up.

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to run Tomcat as root.

You should check your log files, that should give you a little more information about what's going on, you can check your log files here:

```
$TOMCAT/bin/catalina.out
```

It's useful to redirect the tomcat output to the log file and tail it, E.g:

```
./bin/startup.sh > ./logs/catalina.out | tail -f ./logs/catalina.out
```

By the way, in the log you are showing you start tomcat twice.